# What does the 'Use external build' option do in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA, there's a checkbox under Settings > Compiler labeled 'Use external build'. What exactly does it do if the checkbox is checked?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The 'Use External Build' is a new compiler mode that was introduced with IntelliJ Idea 12 to improve the compilation performance and reduce the memory footprint of the IDE itself.

A snippet from **[here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/06/brand-new-compiler-mode-in-intellij-idea-12-leda/)** :

[image]

---

Also from **[here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/compiler.html#generalOptions)**:

[image]

---

Interestingly, I do not see that option in Intellij Idea 13:

[image]

Comment: The old compiler was removed starting IntelliJ 13, i.e. external build is now the only option.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you have `Use external build` ticked, modify a source file and hit Make, the first informational message states exactly which javac (an external one) is being used to compiled the sources.

For example, my project SDK is 1.7 and after compiling with this setting enabled, my Messages log says:

> > (!) Using javac 1.7.0_25 to compile java sources

When this option is unticked, it seems logical that IntelliJ is using a version of javac that is shipped with it.

My best guess is that the `JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 12.1/lib` folder contains some form of internal (perhaps customized) JDK.

As for "which one to use", I would recommend to go with the external compiler, since this will always be up-to-date with the latest jdk that you have installed and configured, and it should also be exactly the same version of javac as used by external build tools such as maven.

Hope this helps...